# Pychecker --keepgoing (import) problem

Tags: python, static-code-analysis, pychecker

i encountered the following problem when i use PyChecker on modules with an import that is not existing. I called PyChecker with the --keepgoing and --only flags:

`PyChecker --keepgoing --only foo.py`

Now i am getting this problem:

`Processing module foo(foo.py)...`
`Can't import module: foo.foo_.*, ignoring.`
`__Caught exception importing module ppms:`
`____File "Python27\Lib\site-packages\pychecker\pcmodules.py", line 540, in setupMainCode()`
`______module = imp.load_module(self.moduleName, handle, filename, smt)`
`____File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>()`
`______from foo.foo_ import *`
`__TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support indexing`

`Warnings...`

`None`

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Isn't that exactly what your asking it to do?  It found the import error and then moved onto the warnings of which there were None?

Comment: i am kinda wondering about this output, you think this is the normal way pychecker works?